# Use ssh key in /var directory on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, github, ssh, ubuntu-18.04

I set up a ssh key for github in my home directory `/vincent`. I want to clone a repository into my `/var/www/html` directory. It seems, that the key is unknown outside of my home directory. What do I have to do, to be able to connect with github in the `/var` directory?

Edit:

When using ssh to clone I get the following error from github

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: How did you configure git and/or ssh to use this key file? What happens when you try to use ssh or git? Do you get any error messages? What do they say?

Comment: I get an error saying, I don't have the right access rights: `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: Are you using `sudo`?  What command exactly are you running to clone?

Answer (score 1):

You can type

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'
git clone ...
```

You will then see *where* ssh is looking for your key.
Said key should be in `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, with `~` being normally `/home/vincent` (not just `/vincent`)